# compiling in vhdl mode within emacs

Tags: macos, unix, emacs, vhdl

Description:

I am currently running emacs on unix (mac osx) and I write vhdl code in emacs vhdl mode. However when I compile I get the error code:

```
vcom -93 -work work /path
/bin/bash: vcom: command not found

Compilation exited abnormally with code 127 at DATE TIME
```

I want to be able to compile vhdl code in vhdl mode. What am I doing wrong? Please provide detailed answer. If you know how to fix this problem please give me step by step instructions on how to do the same as I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: And since when is Modelsim available on OS X?

Comment: To be a little less obtuse compiling a vhdl design file entails analyzing that design with an external tool.  There's vhdl-mode.el that specifies which tools and the default is in general Modelsim, whose compiler is vcom.  Modelsim hasn't been ported to OS X and a quick google doesn't show anyone doing remote execution to a host operating system to which it has been been ported.  There are versions of vhdl-mode.el using different VHDL tools.  The only VHDL tools I'm aware of that run natively on OS X are ghdl and nvc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Mac OS X Emacs app found at [GNU Emacs For Mac OS X](http://emacsformacosx.com/), a universal binary that will run from OS X 10.6.8 to 10.9.2.  It's vhdl-mode configuration includes ghdl should you have it installed.  I'm afraid I haven't used emacs since the great schism between Gnu and a commercial concern in the '80s. I'm a joe or TextMate user myself these days (both of which can handle VHDL syntax, can be user configured (with a bit of googling and reading). The vhdl-mode appears to expect you to set up a Makefile (through menu items and the external VHDL tool). You can generally analyze the current buffer directly.  Creating a Makefile isn't exactly simplistic and is outside the scope of my experience (I went and read several vhdl-mode.el versions before answering, I said I'm not an emacs user).

[image]

Notice it found out which VHDL tools were available and used ghdl.  This is a function found in the vhdl-mode.el file.

If you're running 10.9 Mavericks there's [ghdl-0.31](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/files/Builds/ghdl-0.31/) from [ghdl-updates](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/?source=navbar).  An mcode version of ghdl-0.29 that can run on OS X 10.6 - 10.9 can be found at Tristan's old ghdl site - [GHDL for Mac OS X](http://ghdl.free.fr/site/pmwiki.php?n=Main.Download).

A gtkwave app for OS X can be found on Tony Bybell's [GTKWave](http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net/) SourceForge page.

I understand vhdl-mode.el and (.elc, etc. files) are sensitive to which version of Emacs you're using.  They may not be particularly portable between the Emacs.app (24.3) and /usr/bin/emacs (22.1.1).  If that's not the case I'm sure someone will chime in.

Comment: And from looking at the -ieee=synopsys flag passed to ghdl, I'd be tempted to edit vhdl-mode to remove it.

Comment: @DavidKoontz, you don't need to edit VHDL mode for that, you only need to change the compiler configuration for GHDL (VHDL -> Compile -> Compiler -> Customize Compiler...)

Comment: @youR.Fate - out of curiosity, where are those changes stored if not the vhdl-mode.el file?

Comment: @DavidKoontz those changes are stored in your emacs init file, or your emacs-custom file, if you have configured emacs to use one. How to do that is described here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Customizations.html. I personally use .emacs.d/emacs-custom.el.